# How to edit an embed using Message ID, (Pycord)

Tags: python, pycord

I'm trying to edit an embed in another channel for example Rules channel...

The uprules command is meant to add a field to the previous embed without making another embed.

I'm using Pycord latest version.
Things I've tried are below.

Code:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Rules(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        self.Rules = discord.Embed(
            title = "__**Test Embed Rules**__",
            description = """
Rules
            """
        )

    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def rules(self, ctx):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(954750221261373471)

        await channel.send(embed=self.Rules)

    @commands.command()
    async def uprules(self, ctx, number, *, text):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(954750221261373471)
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(955501538766381066)

        Rules.add_field(
            name="||Test Embed||\n",
            value=f"```css\n[{number}] {text}\n```",
            inline=False
        )

        await msg.edit(embed=self.Rules)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Rules(client))
````

Error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'Rules' has no attribute 'add_field'
```

What I've looked at: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=message%20id#discord.Message.id

That's what I've tried. I'm thinking I could edit the embed using the messages ID but I don't know how exactly. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you probably want to edit a message, not a channel.

Comment: That's what I said in the title. `get_message()` doesn't work. And `get_partial_message` doesn't work either.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I was trying to get the channel id so then it'd find the message in the channel and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this method just doesn't work. I never saw it working before and can't find an entry for it in the documentation.

You need to fetch the message directly with an `await` call in order to edit it.

Like this:

```py
channel = self.client.get_channel(954750221261373471)
msg = await channel.fetch_message(5389540224354334)
```

And for the embed error, you should move the variable to the `__init__` function, in order to use it everywhere without blocking. Like  this:

```py
def __init__(self, client):
   self.client = client

   self.Rules = discord.Embed(
    title = "__**Test Embed Rules**__",
    description = "")
```

After that, can you use the variable `self.Rules` for the required Embed.

---

### Sources

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message

Comment: I don't use Discord.py, but I will look on the Pycord docs thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's the same on pycord.

Comment: Yes , I know it's not working tho. @Razzer

Comment: I've even tried making the embed = discord.Embed() a global variable. And I get and error saying something no attribute dict.

Comment: I updated the code so you can see it. I've also updated the error to the new error.

Comment: Never mind. This has helped me a lot thank you.